# Positioning the logo to center in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using this code for the image:

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"/>
```

I want the logo to be centered , it can be done by varying the Layout margin left  value and check and position it, but is there any command to get it centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `RelativeLayout`:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:contentDescription="application_logo"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to use only `horizonal alignment`, only remove `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` from `XML resource`.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the other part of your layout you could use a set the gravity of it's parent to center_vertical|center_horizontal.

Comment: you should mark this as the answer if it was actually the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the element `android:layout_centerInParent` to center the image in the parent (container)

Answer (score 0):

even better: use an image file the size of the screen (even fi it has balck space around it)